# Using sql queries in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting data from database in following way:

```
 result = (from d in context.FTDocuments
                          join f in context.FTDocFlags on d.ID equals f.DocID into fgrp
                          from x in fgrp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          where d.LevelID == levelID && x.UserID == userID && d.Status.Equals(DocumentStatus.NEW)
                          select new Entities.Document
                          {
                              ArrivalDate = d.ArrivalDate.Value,
                              BundleReference = d.BundleRef,
                              CreatedDate = d.CreatedDate,
                              CustomerID = d.CustomerID,
                              DocType = d.DocType.Value,
                              GuidID = d.DocGuid,
                              ID = d.ID,
                              LastExportID = d.LastExpID,
                              LevelID = d.LevelID,
                              ProfileID = d.ProfileID,
                              ScanDate = d.ScanDate.Value,
                              ScanOperator = d.ScanOperator,
                              SenderEmail = d.SenderEmail,
                              Status = d.Status,
                              VerifyOperator = d.VerOperator,
                              FlagNo = x == null ? 0 : x.FlagNo,
                              FlagUserID = x == null ? 0 : x.UserID
                          }).ToList();
```

Now, I am try to achieve this by using sql queries:

```
var test = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select *from FTDocument d left outer join FTDocFlag f on d.ID=f.DocID").ToList();
```

But get the following error:

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types

Is it possible to use complex queries like above?

I use EF 6.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your query does not return a single string. Use like:

```
var test = context.Database.SqlQuery<Entities.Document>("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const string query = @"select *from FTDocument d left outer join FTDocFlag f on d.ID=f.DocID";

var test = context.Database.SqlQuery<Entity>(query).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my answer I have assumed **EntitityFramework (ObjectContext)** first, but then I have added the code for **DbContext** as well.

To check out the example below, you can use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and add your Entity Framework DLL by using **EntitityFramework(ObjectContext)** via *Add connection.* Specify connection properties and close the connection dialog. Then select the connection and run the example:

```
void Main()
{
    var context=this; // requires that you selected an EF ObjectContext connection  
    var q=context.ExecuteStoreQuery<FTDocument>(
                                   "SELECT * FROM FTDocument WHERE ID = @p0", 1);
    q.ToList().Dump();
}
```

It will accept all kind of SQL queries, and you can use parameters like `@p0`, `@p1` etc and simply append them comma-separated when you invoke the function `ExecuteStoreQuery`. The result will be returned as `List<FTDocument>`. To convert it to `List<string>` you need to specify which database field you want to return - or you create a comma-separated list of field values in each row, for example:

```
    q.Select(s=>s.ID+", "+s.GuidID+", "+s.DocType).ToList().Dump();
```

---

The same example, but this  time with **EntityFramework (DbContext)**:

Add your Entity Framework DLL by using **EntitityFramework(DbContext V4/V5/V6)** via *Add connection.* Specify connection properties (don't forget to specify the AppConfig file) and close the connection dialog. Then select the connection and run the example:

```
void Main()
{
    var context=this; // requires that you selected an EF DBContext (V4/5/6) connection 
    var q=context.Database.SqlQuery<FTDocument>(
                               "SELECT * FROM FTDocument WHERE ID = @p0", 1);
    q.ToList().Dump();
}
```

**Tip:** Before you close the connection dialog, click <kbd>Test</kbd>. It will save you a headache later if you know the connection succeeds. For all those who want to try it out with a different EF project with your own database, [here is](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_database_first_approach.htm) a quick tutorial how to create it. Then simply replace `FTDocument` in the example above by a different table of your choice (in the SQL string and inside the brackets `<...>` of course).